# Two different large array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have problem with two arrays:

```
$pole1 = array(
    array("klic"=>"banan", "jmeno"=>"Banán"),
    array("klic"=>"pomeranc", "jmeno"=>"Pomeranč"),
);

$pole2 = array(
    array("klic"=>"banan"),
);
```

Now I need foreach data:

```
foreach ($pole1 as $key => $val){
    //all data from $pole
    echo $val
    //and here if "klic" from $pole1 == "klic" from $pole2
    if ($pole2[$key]["klic"] == $pole1["klic"]) 
        echo "YES"; // - **not working**
}
```

I need to check if data from `$pole1` equals data from `$pole2` and write some text but I need to write all data from `$pole1`.

Comment: you forgot to use index of item in pole1 `$pole2[$key]["klic"] == $pole1[$key]["klic"]` or alternative: `$pole2[$key]["klic"] == $val["klic"]`

Comment: protip: Nemíchej češtinu do kódu. Blbě se to pak čte - všechno anglicky.

Comment: @MarkS: Only issue with that is he is going to get an out of index error on 2nd iteration because there is only 1 element in $pole2.  So change to `$pole2[0]["klic"] == $pole1[$key]["klic"]`

Comment: you can use http://pk1.php.net/array_search function

Comment: Good point @DanSherwin, if $pole2 can be dynamic, then logic should be reworked, using i.e. foreach inside foreach...

Comment: Agreed. @user3702154 If $pole2 is dynamic, are you wanting to check every entry in $pole1 with every entry in $pole2?

Comment: imo, This will be rather slow for large `pole2` arrays as you have to do a sequential scan to find a match. imo, What you want is something like `$pole2['banan'] = true;` etc. Then you can do an `isset` check. This is linear time.

Answer (score 1):

You meant that?

```
foreach ($pole1 as $key => $val) {
    if ( isset($pole2[$key]["klic"] && 
        ($pole2[$key]["klic"] == $pole1[$key]["klic"]) )
        echo "YES"; 
}
```

Comment: Going to get an out of index error from $pole2 on second iteration since it only has 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($pole1 as $k1 => $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $k2 => $val) {

      if($pole2[$k1][$k2] == $val) {
          // $pole1[$k1][$k2] is equal to $pole2[$k1][$k2]
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will echo every entry in pole1 and check every entry in pole1 with every entry in pole2.

```
foreach($pole1 as $val){
   echo($val);
   foreach($pole2 as $val2){
     if($val['klic']==$val2['klic']) echo 'YES';
   }
}
```

Comment: I just cut and pasted your arrays with my code above and ran it and I got `ArrayYESArray` which is what was expected